# How to fix an error when using Alias in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I am receiving a syntax error when running the following code

42601: syntax error at or near "."

I think it has something to do with the alias but I cannot see where the problem is.

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT 
m.shipment_id
m.route_id,
m.leg_sequence_id,
m.leg_warehouse_id,
m.leg_ship_method,
row_number() over (partition by m.route_id order by m.leg_sequence_id desc) as rn
FROM posimorders.sc_execution_eu.o_detailed_routes_v2 m
) 
WHERE rn=1
LIMIT 100;
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code includes:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT 
m.shipment_id
m.route_id,
...
```

You are missing a comma after `m.shipment_id` so it is trying to interpret `m.route_id` as a column alias for the shipment ID, which isn't what you intended; and an alias is a single identifier rather than a dot-separated hierarchy. Hence the error you are seeing, though that isn't coming from Oracle itself - your client seems to be parsing it first.

Oracle also doesn't support `LIMIT`, but from 12c it has [a row-limiting clause](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#BABBADDD) you can use instead:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT 
  m.shipment_id,
  m.route_id,
  m.leg_sequence_id,
  m.leg_warehouse_id,
  m.leg_ship_method,
  row_number() over (partition by m.route_id order by m.leg_sequence_id desc) as rn
  FROM posimorders.sc_execution_eu.o_detailed_routes_v2 m
) 
WHERE rn=1
FETCH FIRST 100 ROWS ONLY;
```

or `WITH TIES` if you prefer.

The three levels in `posimorders.sc_execution_eu.o_detailed_routes_v2` looks wrong too though... [see the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements009.htm).